# "...up 3% on.." meaning in this context

Tags: prepositions

A sentence in Cambridge Dictionary:

> Last year the company's turnover was $240 billion, **up 3% on** previous year.

As a basic learner I can't determine whether **"up"** here is a preposition or an adverb.

Please Explain.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The company's turnover was up 3% compared to the previous year. I'd say up is being used as an adjective here; turnover is up. It's meaning 2.b. of up as an adjective here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up
Or check here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-of-place-and-movement/up for a rundown of different uses of up.

Comment: What if I wrote "up by 3%.."?